# A lot of HTTP requests and save as json: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, file, http

I have a problem with my code. I need to capture a lot of data by API. First, i had a problem with memory and now I see: connect ETIMEDOUT error

My code:

```js
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
const async = require('async');
const request = require('request');
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var file = '/temp/data.json'
let urls = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 608469; i++) {
  let url = "https://api.demo.com/v2.1/people?user_key=auth_key&page="+i+"&sort_order=created_at%20DESC";
  urls.push(url);
}

function httpGet(url, callback) {
  const options = {
    url :  url,
    json : true
  };
  request(options,
    function(err, res, body) {
      callback(err, body);
    }
  );
}

async.map(urls, httpGet, function (err, res){
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(typeof(res));
  jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, res);
});
```

Comment: `ETIMEDOUT` means the server is taking too long to respond. It has nothing to do with your JS. If it's your server then you need to post the serverside code.

Comment: Ok, after looking at your code it looks like you're DDOSing yourself... Stop what you're doing immediately.

Comment: 600,000 simultaneous requests is nuts

Answer (score 0):

Just replace async's `map` method with `eachLimit`. Key here is `limit`. It still will run http request for each link, but in no more than `limit` paraller threads. Here is a doc: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit